# self-adjoint operator intuition

Tags: inner-products, adjoint-operators, unitary-matrices

can someone please explain self-adjoint operator intuition to me. 
And why when $T^* = T^{-1}$, $T$ preserves the inner product and therefore preserves the the orthonormal basis and the length and distance?
thank you

Comment: Did you mean to write $T^* = T^{-1}$?

Comment: yes, I meant it @littleO

Comment: Ok I edited the question accordingly. The second question (about the condition that $T^* = T^{-1}$ is different and easier to answer than your first question about understanding the intuition behind self-adjoint operators. I'm sure the second question has been answered already on math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about a symmetric matrix, it’s a simpler case. I think that the term arise from an observation: matrices that are diagonal if we describe them with orthonormal bases have a symmetric structure if we change coordinates with an orthogonal transformation. This is a different way to interpret the def immediatley using the specrtal theorem.

Comment: thank you, can you please expand on the different way to interpret the def immediatley using the specrtal theorem?